# Yelp API Business Matches EndPoint

Tags: ios, swift, api, yelp, yelp-fusion-api

I am using the Yelp API to call the business matches endpoint. Unfortunately, I am getting an error that I have been playing around with for a while, but can't seem to find a reason why it is returning me the following response:

```
Optional({
    error =     {
        code = "NOT_FOUND";
        description = "Resource could not be found.";
    };
})
```

The way I am setting up the endpoint is the following:

```
import Foundation
import Moya


private let apiKey = ""


enum YelpService {
    enum BusinessMatch: TargetType {
        case match(name: String, address1: String, city: String, state: String, country: String)

        var baseURL: URL {
            return URL(string: "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/matches")!
        }

        var path: String {
            switch self {
            case .match:
                return "/match"
            }
        }

        var method: Moya.Method {
            return.get
        }

        var sampleData: Data {
            return Data()
        }

        var task: Task {
            switch self {
            case let .match(name, address1, city, state, country):
                return .requestParameters(parameters: ["name": name, "address1": address1, "city": city, "state": state, "country": country, "limit": 1], encoding: URLEncoding.queryString)
            }
        }

        var headers: [String : String]? {
            return ["Authorization": "Bearer \(apiKey)"]
        }
}
}
```

I then call the endpoint with the following:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Moya

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    let service = MoyaProvider<YelpService.BusinessMatch>()


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        service.request(.match(name: "Sushi Damo", address1:
            "330 W 58th St", city: "New York", state: "NY", country: "US")) { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let response):
                    print(try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data, options: []))
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
        }
        return true
}


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "APITest")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Think you're included `/matches` twice. You have it in your `baseURL` and `var path: String`

```
curl -X GET "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/matches\
?name=Sushi%20Damo&address1=330%20W%2058th%20St&city=New%20York&state=NY\
&country=US&limit=1" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer API_KEY"
```

Works for me. But

```
curl -X GET "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/matches/matches\
?name=Sushi%20Damo&address1=330%20W%2058th%20St&city=New%20York&state=NY\
&country=US&limit=1" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer API_KEY"
```

Gives me the error you get.

Suggest changing `baseURL` and `path` to:

```
    public var baseURL: NSURL { return NSURL(string: "https://api.yelp.com")! }

    public var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .match:
            return "/v3/businesses/matches"
        }
    }
```